# Django REST Framework - nested serializer validation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have models like so:

```
class Leaderboard(models.Model):
    pass


class Column(models.Model):
    leaderboard = models.ForeignKey(Leaderboard, related_name="columns", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    related_columns = models.ManyToManyField(self)
    index = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

And serializers like so:

```
class ColumnSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    related_columns = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Column.objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Column
        fields = ('leaderboard', 'related_columns', 'index',)


class LeaderboardSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    children = ColumnSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Leaderboard
        fields = ('columns',)
```

So what I'd like to do is verify that any columns added to `related_columns` for `ColumnSerializer` already belong to its `Leaderboard` parent. I have tried many times to access the Leaderboard or a Leaderboard ID (like by manually specifying `id` in fields) during creation of the `ColumnSerializer` to verify, but LeaderboardSerializer` is not initialized before Column so I cannot verify the details.

Basically, I want to modify `queryset=Column.objects.all()` to be `queryset=self.instance.leaderboard.columns.all()`

However I don't have access to `Leaderboard` inside `Column`. For example, if I access `self.parent.instance/initial` inside `ColumnSerializer` it is `None` until inside `Leaderboard.validate_columns()`. One thing I've thought of is to just do the validation on the Leaderboard side, but I still think it should be "doable" to do this validation inside `Column` in case I ever want to edit those directly, without first going through a `Leaderboard`...

Comment: I think this is what the base validate method would be for. Since your related_columns validation requires knowledge of another field do the check there.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? I'm also looking at validating the child serializer based on information from the parent.

Comment: @FMCorz posted my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem:

```
def validate_columns(self, columns):
    if not columns:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Leaderboards require at least 1 column")

    # Make sure all column indexes are unique
    indexes = [column['index'] for column in columns]
    if len(set(indexes)) != len(columns):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Columns must have unique indexes!")

    # Make sure all column keys are unique
    keys = [column["key"] for column in columns]
    if len(set(keys)) != len(columns):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Columns must have unique keys!")

    # Validate that column.computation_indexes points to valid columns
    for column in columns:
        if 'computation_indexes' in column and column['computation_indexes']:
            for index in column['computation_indexes'].split(","):
                try:
                    if int(index) not in indexes:
                        raise serializers.ValidationError(f"Column index {index} does not exist in available indexes {indexes}")
                except ValueError:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(f"Bad value for index, should be an integer but received: {index}.")

    return columns
```

I make sure that the columns are unique (both in their keys and indexes) and that the columns they are referencing exist as well.